# Trying to write a copy script that allows me to append the target file if it already exist

Tags: copy, overwrite

So this program would allow me to copy files by entering the name of a source file then the name of a destination file. If the destination file already existed i want to give myself the choice to overwrite append or cancel. So far ive been able to get the choice part to work but i cant get the test if the file exist to work along side the choices. Here is what i have so far its not completed but any input on how to make this run would be much appreciated.

```
if [ $1 -f ]
then echo "file exist"
while [ $2 -e ]
read -p "Do you want to (O)verwrite, (A)ppend, or (E)nd? " answer
case ${answer:0:1} in
o|O )
  cp $1 $2
;;
a|A )
  cat $1 >> $2
;;
* )
echo "Cancel"
;;
esac
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its just a typo -

Change

```
if [ $1 -f ]
```

to

```
if [ -f $1 ]
```